# Calculating the sum of rows that have been grouped in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query:

```
SELECT substring(Code,1,6) as Code
From Table
Group by substring(Code,1,6)
Order By Code
```

However I'm trying to add a column that is the calculated sum of the rows that have been grouped in this query. Example:

```
Code    Number

S05080A 20

S05080B 20

S70331A 8

S70331B 4
```

Would then become:

```
Code    Sum

S05080  40

S70331  12
```

Hopefully someone can help me out with this one, would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try adding `, sum(number)` to your `select`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT substring(Code,1,6) as Code,
       SUM(Number) AS [Sum] -- Add this line

From Table

Group by substring(Code,1,6)

Order By Code
```

Comment: Ah that's fantastic, thanks. Works exactly as I had hoped.

Answer (score 1):

You've already done the hard work - simply add `SUM(Number)` as another column and alias it

```
SELECT substring(Code,1,6) as Code, SUM(Number) AS Sum
From Table
Group by substring(Code,1,6)
Order By Code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUM`, like below:

```
SELECT substring(Code,1,6) as Code, SUM(Number) as Sum
From Table
Group by substring(Code,1,6)
Order By Code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
CREATE TABLE #codes(code nvarchar(10), number int)

INSERT INTO #codes(code, number)
VALUES(N'S05080A', 20), (N'S05080B', 20), (N'S70331A', 8), (N'S70331B', 4)

-- This is your part
SELECT LEFT(code,6) as code,SUM(number)
FROM #codes
GROUP BY LEFT(code,6)

DROP TABLE #codes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (Code varchar(10),number int)
insert into @t(code,number)values  ('S05080A',20), ('S05080B',20), ('S70331A',8),('S70331B', 4)

SELECT  SUBSTRING(Code, 1, NULLIF(DATALENGTH(Code)-1,-1)),SUM(number)
From @t
Group by SUBSTRING(Code, 1, NULLIF(DATALENGTH(Code)-1,-1))
Order By SUBSTRING(Code, 1, NULLIF(DATALENGTH(Code)-1,-1))
```